# Каждый раз присваивается новый id сессии

Tags: php, сессия, php8

На основном сайте, через слушатель onpagehide - срабатывает когда пользователь уходит либо закрывает страницу, отправляю post запрос через

```
navigator.sendBeacon('/jx/', JSON.stringify({md:'v', po:'stats', rf:document.referrer,   id:this.id, iframe:(window.frameElement && 1)}));
```

Таким образом, собираю статистику в бд...

Eсли сайт открыт черeз iframe окно. Все тоже работает и авторизация и тд. Но когда отправляется запрос перед закрытием страницы на которой сайт открыт в iframe. По какой та причине, каждый раз присваивается новый PHPSESSION id.

Получается записей в бд, от одного пользователя будет столько сколько раз он закрыл или обновил одну и туже страницу. Причина в том, что каждый раз меняется PHPSESSION при отправке.

Еще раз.
Если сайт открыт в iframe и посмотреть на PHPSESSION - он статичный и не меняется, а если перед закрытием страницы отправить запрос на запись в бд. То в бд видно, что PHPSESSION каждый раз новый. С чем это связано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Старт сессии во всех обращениях

```
session_set_cookie_params(null, '/', ".site.ru");
session_start();
define('SESSION_ID', session_id());
die(SESSION_ID);
```

Comment: А кука с PHPSESSION в запросе отправляется?

Comment: При каждой отправкой, новый сеанс. Добавил скриншет

Comment: При открытии сайта в iframe, сессия не теряется. При отправке ajax в iframe, сессия теряется.  При отправке ajax вне iframe, сессия не теряется. То есть сессия теряется тогда, когда отправляю ajax в iframe окне. Как решить?

Comment: Сейчас проверил, при закрытии окна кука отправляется, id сессии не меняется. Что у вас в `/jx/`? Может как-то неправильно стартуете сессию?

Comment: Во всех случаях старт сессии запускаю. id сессии меняется в том случаи, когда отправляю запрос через navigator.sendBeacon в iframe окне.

Comment: Добавил когда запуска сессии

Comment: Если сайт открыт в iframe окне, сессия не меняется. Меняется когда отправляю ajax в iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши куки должны иметь атрибут SameSite=None и Secure. Он означает, что кука может отправляться при запросе на ваш сайт, даже если запрос не с вашей страницы.

То есть `session_set_cookie_params(['samesite' => 'None', 'secure' => true]);` должно помочь.

Это связано с тем, что сайт открыт в айфрэйме другого сайта. Если хосты совпадают, то проблем нет, кука отправляется всегда. Но если хосты отличаются, кука не отправляется на сервер и сессия стартует заново.

Comment: Вот статья на эту тему https://medium.com/trabe/cookies-and-iframes-f7cca58b3b9e

Comment: Работает.  Возможно сможешь подсказать по данному вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1442355/Одна-и-таже-сессия-на-2-сайтах

Comment: Такой вот вопрос. С id сессией разобрались, у меня в iframe куки не читает. Когда первый раз, пользователь открывает сайт в iframe, куки не читаются. Если внутри iframe пользователь переходит на другую страницу, ани срабатываю, то есть пользователь становится авторизованным. Возможно выполнить так, чтобы при первом открытии сайта в iframe, пользователь стал авторизованным. То есть, чтобы куки были сразу прочитанными.

Comment: Ничего лучшего чем генерировать форму через js и отправлять ее, не нашел(не проверял данный способ, возможно не работает). Но это единственно что я нашел как это решить...

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов нужен какой-то воспроизводимый упрощённый пример. Иначе слишком много неизвестных. Я бы посоветовал создать экспериментальный проект с минимум кода и на нём разобраться как это работает.

Comment: Понятно одно, что куки в iframe считываются тогда когда пользователем совершено 1 действие. Это либо переход по ссылке, либо еще что та. В ближайшее время постараюсь что та придумать с примером